# Apache Toree to connect to a remote spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-toree

Is there a way to connect Apache Toree to a remote spark cluster? I see the common command is

```
jupyter toree install --spark_home=/usr/local/bin/apache-spark/
```

How can I go about using spark on a remote server without having to install locally?

Comment: Further more, is there a  way to connect to remote spark **yarn** cluster.

Answer (score 7):

There is indeed a way of getting Toree to connect to a remote Spark cluster.

The easiest way I've discovered is to clone the existing Toree Scala/Python kernel, and create a new Toree Scala/Python Remote kernel.  That way you can have the choice of running locally or remotely.

**Steps:**

1. Make a copy of the existing kernel.  On my particular Toree install, the path to the Kernels was located at: `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/`, so I performed the following command:
   `cp -pr /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/ /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala_remote/`
2. Edit the new `kernel.json` file in `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala_remote/` and add the requisite Spark options to the `__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__` variable.  Technically, only `--master <path>` is required, but you can also add --num-executors, --executor-memory, etc to the variable as well.
3. Restart Jupyter.

My kernel.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "display_name": "Toree - Scala Remote",
  "argv": [
    "/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala_remote/bin/run.sh",
    "--profile",
    "{connection_file}"
  ],
  "language": "scala",
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/spark/python:/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip",
    "SPARK_HOME": "/opt/spark",
    "DEFAULT_INTERPRETER": "Scala",
    "PYTHON_EXEC": "python",
    "__TOREE_OPTS__": "",
    "__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__": "--master spark://192.168.0.255:7077 --deploy-mode client --num-executors 4 --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 8 --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that if environment variable `SPARK_OPTS` exists, then it will take precedence, and `__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__` will have any effect. If that's the case, one should go and modify `SPARK_OPTS` instead of `__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__`

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible example with some intuitive details for ANY remote cluster install. For my remote cluster, which is a Cloudera 5.9.2 these are specific steps. (You can also use this example to install with non-Cloudera clusters with some smart edits.)

**With OS/X to build CDH version (skip if using a distribution):**

1. Goto https://github.com/Myllyenko/incubator-toree and clone this repo
2. Download Docker
3. Setup 'signing' - It's been a some time since I set this up - you'll need to sign the build above. TBD
4. 'new branch git', edit the .travis.xml, README.md, and build.sbt files to change 5.10.x to 5.9.2
5. Start Docker, cd within the `make release` dir, build with `make release`, wait, wait, sign 3 builds
6. Copy the file `./dist/toree-pip/toree-0.2.0-spark-1.6.0-cdh5.9.2.tar.gz`  to your spark-shell machine that can reach your YARN-controlled Spark cluster
7. Merge, commit, etc your repo to your master repo if this will be mission critical

**Spark Machine Installs:**

Warning: Some steps may need to be done as root as a last resort

1. Install pip / anaconda (see other docs)
2. Install Jupyter `sudo pip install jupyter`
3. Install toree `sudo pip install toree-0.2.0-spark-1.6.0-cdh5.9.2` or use the apache-toree distribution

**Configure Toree to run with Jupyter (example):**
Edit & add to `~/.bash_profile`

```
echo $PATH
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
echo $PATH

export CDH_SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.2-1.cdh5.9.2.p0.3/lib/spark
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/etc/spark/conf
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop
PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export PATH
echo $PATH

export SPARK_PKGS=$(cat << END | xargs echo | sed 's/ /,/g'
com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0
END
)

export SPARK_JARS=$(cat << END | xargs echo | sed 's/ /,/g'
/home/mymachine/extras/someapp.jar
/home/mymachine/extras/jsoup-1.10.3.jar
END
)

export TOREE_JAR="/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/lib/toree-assembly-0.2.0-spark-1.6.0-cdh5.9.2-incubating.jar"

export SPARK_OPTS="--master yarn-client --conf spark.yarn.config.gatewayPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels --conf spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR --conf spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.2-1.cdh5.9.2.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.2-1.cdh5.9.2.p0.3/lib/hadoop --conf spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.2-1.cdh5.9.2.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.2-1.cdh5.9.2.p0.3/lib/hadoop --conf spark.yarn.am.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.2-1.cdh5.9.2.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.2-1.cdh5.9.2.p0.3/lib/hadoop --conf spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://yourCDHcluster.net:18088  --conf spark.default.parallelism=20  --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=1g --conf spark.driver.memory=1g  --conf spark.executor.cores=4 --conf spark.executor.instances=5  --conf spark.executor.memory=1g --packages $SPARK_PKGS --jars $SPARK_JARS"

function jti() {
    jupyter toree install \
    --replace \
    --user \
    --kernel_name="CDH 5.9.2 Toree" \
    --debug \
    --spark_home=${SPARK_HOME} \
    --spark_opts="$SPARK_OPTS" \
    --log-level=0
}
function jn() {
    jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8888 --debug --log-level=0
}
```

If you want a different port to hit Toree - now is your chance to edit `8888`

4. Log out of your Toree / spark-shell machine
5. ssh back to that machine `ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 toreebox.cdhcluster.net` (assuming that `8888` is the port in the bash file)
6. I expect as a user (not root) you can type `jti` to install Toree into Jupyter (Note: understanding this step may help to install other kernels into Jupyter - sidebar: @jamcom mentioned
   the produced file, but this step automatically produces this part. The file is buried in your home dir's tree as a user rather than root.
7. As user, type `jn` to start a Jupyter Notebook. Wait a few seconds until the browser url is available and paste that URL into your browser.
8. You now have Jupyter running and so pick a new `CDH 5.9.2 Toree` or the version you installed. This launches a new browser window. Since you have some Toree experience, pick something like `sc.getConf.getAll.sortWith(_._1 < _._1).foreach(println)` in order to get the lazily instantiated spark context going. Be really patient as your jobs is submitted to the cluster and your may have to wait a long time if your cluster is busy or a little while for your job to process in the cluster.

**Tips and Tricks:**

I ran into an issue on the first run and the subsequent runs never saw that issue. (The issue issue might be fixed in the github)

Sometimes, I have to kill the old 'Apache Toree' app on YARN to start a new Toree.

Sometimes, my VM can has an orphaned JVM. If you get memory errors starting a Jupyter Notebook/ Toree or have unexpectedly disconnected, check your process list with `top`. And  ... kill the extra JVM (be careful ID-ing your lost process).